# Creating table from another table update issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

When I insert a record into table A, it doesnt update table B that has been derived from Table A. I have used a where clause as I only want certain records from Table A in my Table B. This is my code

CREATE TABLE B AS (
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE STATUS='STUDENT'
);

When inserting a new record into table A with the new attribute "student" it doesnt update table B. Thank you!

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: First of all is this MySQL or SQL Server your tags at the bottom are contradictory different systems have different ways of running SQL.

Comment: Why are you duplicating your data like this? This breaks normalization rules, just use a view if you want something separate that only lists students.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement: `CREATE TABLE B AS ( SELECT * FROM A WHERE STATUS='STUDENT' );` simply creates a table using the structure resulting from your `SELECT` statement, then copies the results of that statement into the new table. It does not keep an up-to-date match of the original table. You might want to look into a `VIEW` if that is what you want.

You can try:

```
CREATE VIEW B AS SELECT * FROM A WHERE STATUS = 'STUDENT';
```

Comment: the reason i have created a table like this is that table A has a foreign key in table C ONLY IF status="student"

Comment: It sounds like, unless this is an inherited database, you should re-examine your requirements and alter the structure of your database. You should not have "conditional" foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to you can automate it by creating a trigger with a Trigger the information is entered into table B when you insert the row into table A I tried the best I could with the condition you may have to tweak ir a little. **INSERTED** is used in triggers as the vlaue inserted

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger
ON DBO.TableA
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS

IF EXITS (SELECT * 
         FROM TABLE_B
          WHERE (SELECT STATUS 
                 FROM INSERTED I 
                 WHERE STATUS = STUDENT))

BEGIN

   INSERT INTO TableB

   SELECT * 
   FROM INSERTED I 
   WHERE STATUS='STUDENT'
END

ELSE 

  RAISEERROR('ROW IS NOT A STUDENT');
```

Is would be better practoce as @rabbit said bu creating a view with the data needed and now another table the view would grab everything you needed real time:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
SELECT * FROM A WHERE STATUS='STUDENT'
```

YOu create the view as another table basically and call it whenever you need it and it will query the data you need real time. And you can use it just like a table if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE B AS ( SELECT * FROM A WHERE STATUS='STUDENT' );
```

This query will run only once and while running it will insert records present at that time in A to B.This is working as expected.

If you want that everytime a new record is inserted in A some data to be entered in B ,then use triggers.Triggers are auto executed before or after triggering events(trigger_event like INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE).

Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html for more details on triggers